# Determine a playing-card flush hand

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

In a card application I use 0-51 to represent the 5 card hand.

The suit is `card / 13`
The rank is `card %`
There are only 4 possible suit (spade, heart, club diamond)

If all five suit are the same it is a flush.  All flush are of equal value.  Spades is the same as diamonds.

I know you are going to say pre-optimization is evil but I am running some simulations doing this million of times and this is the most expensive step.  The card could be byte but the calculation seem to be faster with int.  I don't really check the range but I put that in so you would know there is a range.

Is there a more efficient way?

```
public bool IsFlush(int[] quick)
{
    HashSet<int> suit = new HashSet<int>();
    suit.Add(quick[0] / 13);
    int thisQuick;
    for (int i = 1; i < quick.Length; i ++)
    {
        thisQuick = quick[i];
        if (thisQuick < 0 || thisQuick > 51)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        if (suit.Add(thisQuick / 13))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Native "word"-sized integers will always be faster than smaller units like `byte` - because that's the unit size the processor is built around. For x86 it's `Int32` for x64 it's `Int64`. Unfortunately C# doesn't not have a "`FastInt`" alias unlike C++, so you'll need a separate code-path for x64 if you really care about this particular microoptimization.

Comment: Also, integer division is very expensive - I'd wager that will consume more wall-clock time than `Byte` vs `Int32` vs `Int64`.

Comment: Note that hashtables, by their nature, are not completely cheap - as they have to allocate a large-enough bucket table and perform key hashing and equality checks. Given a deck has only 52 cards I think you'd be better off with a simple native array.

Comment: @Dai I don't get what you mean by native array?

Comment: @Paparazzi e.g. `int[]`

Comment: @BJMyers But `int[]` does not have an `if add` feature

Comment: If you represented a hand as a bitmask there would be a nice trick

Comment: @harold Tell me more.   I am open.

Comment: @Paparazzi given a hand represented that way, you have a flush if `(hand & hearts) == hand || (hand & diamonds) == hand || (hand & clubs) == hand || (hand & spades) == hand`, which are all fast operations.

Comment: You could also speed up performance of this specific method by doing things in other parts of your code. For example, you could have your hand sorted by suit after the cards are dealt. Then you would only need to check the first and last card's suit and wouldn't even need to iterate the hand.

Comment: @StephenPorter Sort is kind of expensive

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, it would be an upfront cost for optimized performance down the line. The question was how to improve this method, and that is one way to do it. Basically, you deal the hand and then sort by suit then rank. Now you can take advantage of the fact that you know it's sorted before checking for flushes, straights, etc. The question is, does that upfront cost outweigh the performance saved down the line or not? That's how it goes when you begin to micro-optimize :)

Comment: Also, when you think about it, the sort would be purely an int sort. If `suit = i / 13` and `rank = 1 % 13` then to sort by suit then rank would mean that you want to sort by smallest int to largest int. There are highly optimized sorting algorithms (e.g. radix sort) that work well with pure integer sorting.

Comment: @StephenPorter  Sort is going to be more expensive than direct comparison.    At worst have 4 direct comparison.

Comment: @Paparazzi As stated, this all depends on your program. If you deal 5 hands and then check through each hand through a series of operations to see what their best hand is (is it a pair, three of a kind, flush, full house, etc) for each of the 5 hands for each stage of the round, I would argue an initial sort of their hands after dealing them will save you far more run-time (and be far easier to code for) down the line for all of those other operations. Like I said, when you want to micro-optimize to this level, it's involves examining every aspect of the program vs a single method.

Comment: The bitmask tricks enables some more tricks as well, for example if it's a flush then you can use `x = hand + (hand & -hand); if ((x & x - 1) == 0) { // straight flush`

Comment: @StephenPorter And I would argue you are wrong.  Flush is independent of those other things.  A sort on suit is more expensive than a direct comparison.  The direct comparison is O(n) and there are no O(n) sorts.

Comment: @harold I wish you would be more explicit about how to use a bitmask.

Comment: @Paparazzi represent each card by `1L << card` and add all the ones that are in a hand, then a hand is represented by a single `long`. For example `hearts` that I used is a similar `long` but created by representing all hearts that way and adding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminating the `HashSet` should speed things up a bit:

```
public static bool IsFlush(int[] hand)
{
    int firstSuit = hand[0] / 13;
    for (int i = 1; i < hand.Length; i++)
    {
        int card = hand[i];
        if (card < 0 || card > 51)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        if (firstSuit != (card / 13))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My (admittedly meager) testing shows about a 20% performance improvement.

Comment: I just thought of this myself.  +1

Comment: I got more then 20%.

Comment: If you are making the assumption that your deck is perfect (e.g. there is no way you could have cards of the same suit with the same rank (as per our conversation in the other answer)), then why not make the assumption that there is no way you have a card less than 0 or more than 51? Then you could save CPU ticks by not checking for the IndexOutOfRange criteria.

Comment: I tried that in my benchmarks, and it turned out to have almost no effect on the runtime of my code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use bitfields to store information about cards, it might be faster, that way you can avoid the expense of integer division and modulo operations.

```
const Int32 SuitMask = 0x001100000;
const Int32 Spade    = 0x000000000;
const Int32 Heart    = 0x000100000;
const Int32 Diamond  = 0x001000000;
const Int32 Club     = 0x001100000;

public static Boolean AllCardsInHandOfSameSuit(Int32[] hand) {

    Int32 countSpades   = 0;
    Int32 countHeart    = 0;
    Int32 countDiamonds = 0;
    Int32 countClubs    = 0;

    foreach( Int32 card in hand ) {

        Int32 suit = card & SuitMask;
        switch( suit ) {
            case Spade:
                countSpades++;
                break;
            case Heart:
                countHearts++;
                break;
            case Diamond:
                countDiamonds++;
                break;
            case Club:
                countClubs++;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Your question is not worded clearly about whether or not you care about unique ranks, only unique suits:
    // I'm also unsure of your flush/hand rules, but just compare the counts as-required:
    Boolean allSameSuit = 
        ( countSpades   == 0 || countSpades   == hand.Length ) &&
        ( countHearts   == 0 || countHearts   == hand.Length ) &&
        ( countDiamonds == 0 || countDiamonds == hand.Length ) &&
        ( countClubs    == 0 || countClubs    == hand.Length );

    Boolean allDifferentSuit =
        countSpades   <= 1 &&
        countHearts   <= 1 &&
        countDiamonds <= 1 &&
        countClubs    <= 1;

}
```

To generate values for cards:

```
public static Int32 CreateCard(Int32 suit, Int32 rank) {

    return suit | ( rank & 0x0000 );
}
```

For example:

```
Int32[] deck = new Int32[52];
for( Int32 i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++ ) {

    Int32 suit =
        i / 13 == 0 ? Spade :
        i / 13 == 1 ? Heart :
        i / 13 == 2 ? Diamond : Club;

    deck[i] = CreateCard( suit, i % 13 );
}

Int32[] hand = new Int32[4];
for( Int32 i = 0; i < hand.Length; i++ ) {
    hand[i] = deck[ GetRandomIndexPreviouslyUnused() ];
}
```

Comment: You could go even more crazy on micro-optimizations and use bytes instead (8 bits gives you more than you need). You could put `i / 13` into a variable to compute it only once per iteration (more memory, but faster computation). Though, make sure you create this variable outside the loop and reassign in the loop so you only use one spot in memory. Then for flush check, iterate the hand and the moment the next suit doesn't match the previous suit, return false. Worst case, you iterate the whole hand, best case, you only iterate two cards in the hand.

Comment: I will check this out.  Rules on flush is stated.  "If all five suit are the same it is a flush."   If it is a flush then all cards must be of different rank.

Comment: True, you'd have to throw in a rank check as well... best case is still iterating only two cards though (if their suits don't match you don't even need to check the rank).

Comment: @StephenPorter No you don't need a rank check.  In 5 cards if they are all the same suite you have a flush (or straight flush).   No additional checks are required.  If you have a flush it cannot be a boat or quads.

Comment: I see where this is going but right now refactoring card would be a bit of work.

Comment: @Paparazzi You are correct that you could assume that if all the suits are the same that their ranks are the same. The rank check would be more for the realm of error checking to make sure you didn't receive two ranks of the same suit.

Comment: @StephenPorter Ranks NOT the same

Comment: @Paparazzi haha yes, I meant 'you could assume that their ranks are NOT the same' :)